# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot cast class com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub to interface

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

Created a remote EJB project and deployed in the IBM websphere server as Jar.
Now, i created a EJB Client project in my local and trying to connected as Remote call.
but it is throwing an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException

### client Program:

```
package ejb3.test;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;

public class TestEJBClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://(ip of remote ejb server):2809");

    ITestEJBRemoteInterface loEJB = null;
    Object lobj;

    try {

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment());
        lobj = ctx.lookup("ejb3/test/ITestEJBRemoteInterface");// look up of corba
        System.out.println("--------" + lobj);

        loEJB = (ITestEJBRemoteInterface)     PortableRemoteObject.narrow((org.omg.CORBA.Object) lobj, ITestEJBRemoteInterface.class);
        String lsName = "Kevin";
        // Invoke the Method using bean object ;
        System.out.println("Is " + lsName + " present in the list:: " + loEJB.checkNames(lsName));
        System.out.println("EJB run successful");
    }
    catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

### exception:

```
{com.ibm.websphere.naming.hostname.normalizer=com.ibm.ws.naming.util.DefaultHostnameNormalizer, java.naming.factory.initial=com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory, com.ibm.websphere.naming.name.syntax=jndi, com.ibm.websphere.naming.namespace.connection=lazy, com.ibm.ws.naming.ldap.ldapinitctxfactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, com.ibm.websphere.naming.jndicache.cacheobject=populated, com.ibm.websphere.naming.namespaceroot=defaultroot, com.ibm.ws.naming.wsn.factory.initial=com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory, com.ibm.websphere.naming.jndicache.maxcachelife=0, com.ibm.websphere.naming.jndicache.maxentrylife=0, com.ibm.ws.naming.wsn.localonly=false, com.ibm.websphere.naming.jndicache.cachename=providerURL, java.naming.provider.url=iiop://10.176.106.207:2809, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.ibm.ws.naming:com.ibm.ws.naming:com.ibm.ws.naming:com.ibm.ws.naming:com.ibm.ws.naming}
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: WSVR0072W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
INFO: Client code attempting to load security configuration
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
AUDIT: security.LoadSCI
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
AUDIT: security.GettingConfig
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
WARNING: ssl.default.password.in.use.CWPKI0041W
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
INFO: ssl.disable.url.hostname.verification.CWPKI0027I
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
AUDIT: security.AuthTarget
Feb 18, 2016 7:39:53 PM null null
AUDIT: security.ClientCSI
--------com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub:IOR: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
Exception in thread "P=592906:O=0:CT" java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot cast class com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub to interface ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface
    at com.ibm.rmi.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:396)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:148)
    at ejb3.test.TestEJBClient.main(TestEJBClient.java:38)
```

How could i resolve that error?
Can any one please share your thoughts.

Comment: It appears that the JNDI name is a context rather than a binding.  Can you show the output of the `PROFILE_HOME/bin/dumpNameSpace` command?

Comment: Hi Brett, i ran the dumpNameSpace this the location where my  interface is residing node/applications/com.ibm.ws.AppNameSpaces/TestEJB(1)/root/TestEJB(1)/TestEJB!ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface .    when i try to give that it lookup, i am not sure how it will look for the remote server ejb

Comment: That's a somewhat "internal" name for java:app, which I don't think is intended to be used directly or out of process.  Can you find an entry corresponding to `ejb3/test/ITestEJBRemoteInterface` that you did attempt to look up?  Perhaps put the full output on pastebin if it's too large to put here?

Comment: please find the output log, which im hitting the server http://www.filedropper.com/text_3

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassCastException - if narrowFrom cannot be cast to narrowTo.
```

Seems that corba.object and itestejbrremoteinterface are not related by inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The relevant lines from the dumpNameSpace are:

```
  168 (top)/nodes/CLEVDICM-143Node01/servers/server1/ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface
  168                                                    ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface

  192 (top)/nodes/CLEVDICM-143Node01/servers/server1/ejb/TestEJB(1)_jar/TestEJB(1).jar/TestEJB#ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface
  192                                                    ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface
```

The root of the server context is `(top)/nodes/CLEVDICM-143Node01/servers/server1/`, which means you should use one of these strings:

1. `ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface`
2. `ejb/TestEJB(1)_jar/TestEJB(1).jar/TestEJB#ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface`